# The python-telegram-bot library does not see messages in a group

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I’m writing a Python3 script that runs a function after 10 messages have arrived in a telegram channel. I used the python-telegram-bot v. 13.3 library, created a telegram bot, added it to the channel, and gave admin permissions, but the script is like it doesn’t see messages. This is the code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import telegram
TOKENB = 'Token Here'
CHANNEL_ID = 'Id Here'
counter = 0

def check_messages(update, context):
    global counter
    chat = context.bot.get_chat(CHANNEL_ID)
    if update.message.chat_id == chat.id:
        counter += 1
        print(f"Messaggio {counter} nel canale rilevato!")
        if counter >= 10:
            Function()
            print("Sono stati ricevuti 10 messaggi nel canale, eseguo la funzione...")
            counter = 0


def main():
    updater = telegram.ext.Updater(TOKENB, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.MessageHandler(telegram.ext.Filters.all & telegram.ext.Filters.chat(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID), check_messages))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please note that v13.x and older are no longer supported by the PTB dev team and we encourage to upgrade to v20.x.